# Reading, updating and writing XML document with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, formatting, config

I want to read, update and then write back to disk a Web.config file which is an XML.
The way I'm doing it right now is:

```
[xml]$config = Get-Content -Path $ConfigPath
# Update...
$config.Save($ConfigPath)
```

The thing is that it messes up a little bit the initial config formatting. I have some nodes, for example:

```
<add key="DEBUG_API_ABC" value='
{
  "A": {
    "B": "asd",
    "C": "qwe"    
  }
}
'/>
```

And it makes it like:

```
<add key="DEBUG_API_ABC" value=" {   &quot;..."/>
```

I would like to save it exactly as it is found, keeping the format, the text spacing, only injecting some values when updating. Is it possible?

Comment: check the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160613/powershell-saving-xml-and-preserving-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to load an XML document (not only in PowerShell) is to use the XML parser to load it and avoid `Get-Content`, because `Get-Content` will happily mangle the file encoding if it gets a chance.

You seem to have an XML file with JSON data in an attribute, which is odd, but let's work with what you have:

```
$config = New-Object xml

$config.Load $ConfigPath

$debugApi = $config.selectSingleNode("//add[@key='DEBUG_API_ABC']")

$configData = $debugApi.getAttribute("value") | ConvertFrom-JSON
$configData.A.B = "new value"

$configJson = $configData | ConvertTo-JSON
$debugApi.setAttribute("value", $configJson)

$config.Save($ConfigPath)
```

`ConvertTo-JSON` will pretty-print its output by default, so while it will probably not maintain the "original" white-space layout in the JSON, it will still result in a recognizable structure in the XML.

---

Regarding the question *"Can I keep the `"` instead of `&quot;` in the attribute value?"*

No, you can't. Here's why:

When it comes to serializing "special" characters (of which XML does not have many, but `"` and `'` are two), XML DOM APIs are opinionated. For example, `value='something " something'` is valid XML and will cause the `@value` attribute of the node in question to get the string value `something " something` in RAM after parsing.

However, when that string is serialized again, `value="something &quot; something"` is 100% exactly the same thing - but in order to reproduce the original layout, a parser would need to remember that in the original file, that particular attribute had single quote delimiters.

This is a lot of extra work, it would slow down parsing, it would take more memory, and doing it would not make the end result *more correct*. So parsers generally don't, and they use a default that's just as correct but *much* easier to produce.

For example, the DOM API's opinion on serialization could be *"all attributes use double quotes as delimiters, therefore all double quotes in attribute values will be escaped"*, and that's completely fine because it will retain data integrity and that's all that matters.

It will also "normalize" all single-quoted attributes into double-quoted ones, making JSON in attributes harder to read. But part of that problem is that maybe storing JSON in XML is not the best choice to begin with, at least as long you're relying on human editors.

Comment: I don't modify the JSON keys, I modify other keys, but those ones get affected in the process of saving and they get shrinked. The topic of my question is keeping the exact format as I find it in the file, only injecting some values in some nodes, but not mainly JSON ones as in the example.

Comment: @Garbem I don't like breaking it to you, but you can't. Get over it.

Comment: @Garbem XML is not a way of laying out text in files. XML is a way of storing *data* in files. Loading the file, modifying it and storing it again will guarantee the integrity of the data, that was the design goal of XML. It will not guarantee "that everything looks the same as before in a text editor" - that was never a design goal, and it's out of reach with most, if not all, XML parsers. Don't create situations where stuff depends on how an XML file looks in a text editor, is the only sane way to deal with this.